# Layered Navigiation Not Showing

Tags: magento2, category, price, layered-navigation

I have done alot of tutorials to enable layered navigation like this one - [Link](https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/magento-2-how-to-enable-layered-navigation/)

However all i get on the left column bar is this the compare products list. All i want to add is the price ranges and sub category like this

[image]

Is there something i am missing ??? I am using M2 community 2.2.2

Any help is appreciated , however i am not a computer programmer and dont know anything about coding.

Answer (score 0):

I cant open the link so i don`t know if the tutorials you followed covered this but a common problem is that the categories that you want to show are not set to anchor -> true

go to Catalog>Category click on the category that you want to put in your navigation open the "Display settings" tab on the right and make sure that anchor is set to yes.